# Determine variable vector compontent so vectors are independent

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given the vectors $u_1$, $u_2$ $u_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $u_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}
>        1 \\
>        2 \\ 1
>      \end{array}\right)$, $u_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}
>        4 \\
>        5 \\ 2
>      \end{array}\right)$
>   , $u_3=\left(\begin{array}{c}
>        2 \\
>        6t-1 \\ 7t
>      \end{array}\right)$ 
>   determine $t$ so $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are lineary independent

I know that for those three vectors to be independent,  $$\lambda u_1 + µu_2+\phi u_3=\mathbf{0}$$ may only be true for $$\lambda,µ,\phi=0$$ So to solve the task I need to determine a value for $t$ so there's inequality in the first equation for all scalars != 0.
How do I find a value for $t$ so all this is satisfied?

Comment: Is $v_1, v_2, v_3$ a typo? If not, you should clarify which vectors are

Comment: typo, sorry for that

Comment: What are $u_1$ and $u_2$?

Comment: added the given vectors

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+det+%7B%7B1%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B4%2C5%2C2%7D%2C%7B2%2C6t-1%2C7t%7D%7D+%29+%21%3D+0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three linear vectors are independent iff the determinant of the matrix built with them is non zero. Hence we study

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}1&4&2\\2&5&6t-1\\1&2&7t\end{pmatrix} = -9t-4.$$

This determinant is non-zero iff $t\ne -\frac 49$.

Comment: Yeah following Tomas's comment I already figured that out, but thanks for putting it in an answer.

Comment: can you please detail why the determinant has to be non-zero ? Or point me, please, to some place linking the determinant to linear independence